# Outlook addin to send via a portal instead of email

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We're looing at developing an outlook addin to send an email using a secure portal - Would be a separate button on the toolbar, select a contact, add a subject, body and attachments and we would then pass to our web app and send.

This possible (and still give a good UX). We need this to work on both the desktop app (Windows/Mac) and the mobile apps.

Any suggestions on the best approach/gotchas?
thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to add a new command to the toolbar, duplicate of the New Message (called something different), with the same form, but intercept the send action to go to our service instead?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins work under the currently selected or opened in the inspector window item only. You can't pick up any items like you could do with COM add-ins. But you can place a button (command) to the ribbon with your add-in where you could run actions on the currently displayed item or create a response and prepopulate it, see [Add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) for more information. Note, you can use the `EWS` or `Graph API` for accessing any other items in the profile.

Comment: Ah got it. So the command can only work in the context of an existing message. That's a bummer as it won't work as we needed. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers.

Comment: Second with @Eugene, presently Outlook web add-ins run in the context of an item only. Although you can post this as a feature request. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions